# better way to extract domain name from FQDN

Tags: bash

I am extracting the domain name from the FQDN this way:

```
fqdn=$(hostname -f)
domain=$(echo "$fqdn" | rev | cut -f2,1 -d'.' | rev)
```

Results:

```
fqdn: "server.dc1.something.hello.com"
domain: "hello.com"

fqdn: "11.22.33"
domain: "22.33"

fqdn: "11.22.33.44"
domain: "33.44"
```

This works, but the way how I generate the domain name is so complicated. Hard to read, plus it starts with an `echo`.
Is there any better, simplier way to extract the last two words with the dot (`.`) from the end of my string?

Comment: In addition to those problems, it won't work for in many country TLDs. E.g. `server.company.co.uk` the domain is `company.co.uk`, not `co.uk`.

Comment: You can use a here-string `<<<"$fqdn"` instead of piping `echo`. `$(rev <<<"$fqdn" | ...)`

Comment: I tried to figure out a way to do it using parameter expansion operators, but it doesn't look easy. It's easy to get just the first or last component, but hard to get the last *two* components.

Comment: Yes, it seems easy, but it is not.

Comment: Have you tried : `[[ $fqdn =~ ([^.]+\.[^.]+$) ]] ; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` ?

Comment: To add to Barmar's comment about `.co.uk` -- you may be interested in https://publicsuffix.org/, which is what browsers use in order to decide if two domains are "the same site" for various purposes, e.g. the `SameSite` attribute of cookies; for example, "company.co.uk" is one site, because "co.uk" is on the list and "company.co.uk" is not.

Comment: what is your definition of "domain name" ? Why is `22.33` considered to be one?

Comment: `domain=$(dnsdomainname)` - skip the middle-man...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
domain=${fqdn#"${fqdn%.*.*}".}
```

- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of the string manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

While you can simply remove `hostname` from `hostname.domain.tld` with POSIX *parameter expansion with substring removal* where trimming from the left the first occurrence of *pattern* is `${var#pattern}`, e.g. in your case:

```bash
  domain="${fqdn#*.}"
```

Globbing is allowed as part of the *pattern* `*.` so you can simply "trim everything from the left through, and including, the first occurrence of `'.'`".

However, there is no need to trim anything as the `dnsdomainname` utility will fetch the domain component directly, e.g.

```bash
  domain=$(dnsdomainname)
```

You can do it either way, but using `hostname=$(hostname)` and `domain=$(dnsdomainname)` gets right to the point.

If you have questions, drop a comment and I'm happy to help further.